# R-Studio. Error after installing lubridate: could not find function "dmy_hm"

Tags: r, lubridate

First I installed lubridate:

```
install.packages("lubridate") Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Llorenc  Piera/AppData/Roaming/SPB_Data/R/win-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL  'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/lubridate_1.7.4.zip' Content type 'application/zip' length 1365606 bytes (1.3 MB) downloaded 1.3 MB

package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

> Warning in install.packages :   cannot remove prior installation of
>   package ‘lubridate’

Then I try to run:

```
dmy_hm('01-01-2012 12:12')
```

and get:

> Error in dmy_hm("01-01-2012 12:12") : could not find function "dmy_hm"

This used to work in my computer a few weeks ago, but not any more.

Howerver, if I run:

```
lubridate::dmy_hm('01-01-2012 12:12')
```

I get

```
[1] "2012-01-01 12:12:00 UTC"
```

But using 'lubridate::' is not good for me since it does not work inside other functions

Comment: Did you load the package before using the function?

Comment: Yes I did. One thing after the other

Comment: Base on @Rob's input, try `lubridate::dmy_hm('01-01-2012 12:12')`.

Comment: Also note that it did not replace the prior installation of the package. You could try to go to the path `.libPaths()` returns and manually remove the lubridate-directory. After that, re-install it.

Comment: @Llorenç please refer to my answer

Comment: did you **really** run `library("lubridate")` before trying to run `dmy_hm(...)` ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
lubridate::dmy_hm('01-01-2012 12:12')
```

means:
 run the `dmy_hm` function from `lubridate` package. 
   but you need to have the `library(lubridate)`

if you are using Rstudio, then follow these steps:

Use easier options to install a package. Such as `Packages -> Intall -> name of package`

Then in the `package` tab, and search for the `lubridate` and make sure it is checked.

The below image shows how to do it.

[image]

Comment: You are right! Lubridate was not checked. After doing library(lubridate) it was checked and everything started working properly. What does the check stand for? I had never paid attention to that

Comment: The use of double colon operator has nothing to do with global or local installation (with local I assume adding a new library for local use, for example in different projects). It just gets the function from that package, no matter where it is installed--as long as it is installed in a path that is listed when calling `.libPaths()`. Check `?"::"` for reference. Thus, this answer is not entirely correct and not worth accepting, imho.

Comment: @Tino thanks for information. I have updated my answer, please remove your downvote.