# R studio - Error in install.packages

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

It is few hours I started to learn R and I encountered problem while installing ggplot2 package. 
Problem:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = FALSE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ramal/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ggplot2_3.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3579116 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB

Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/Ramal/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/file1d0849aa2ba8/ggplot2/help/figures/logo.png': Permission denied
```

it is last version of R. and this question have been asked before in here. 
but answers was not helpful to me. Could you help me in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Seems to be a permission issue. Log in as the administrator and then install the packages

Comment: please find my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003727/r-studio-error-after-installing-lubridate-could-not-find-function-dmy-hm/52003932#52003932

Comment: it is safer if you use RStudio features to install packages.

Comment: Thanks very much all, it was because of  antivirus.